# TimeSliderChoropleth map with Folium python not showing time slider correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to plot choroploth map with plugins "TimeSliderChoropleth" to shows how "House Sold" in area which integrated with slider, but it shows incorrect slider also it shows only 1 specific time which even doesn't exist in dataframe and also, it's connecting all area value for same "House Sold" in each TimeSlider shifted.

[Folium Map with Wrong TimeSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTYME.png)

This is my dataframe looks like

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqNrT.png)

Also, I modified date and did an epochs conversion to the date

[Datetime feature for slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udn0C.png)

This is styledata lookslike

[Styledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uWJQ.png)

Here's converting "House Sold" for colors code

[Time converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWexU.png)

This is part when I put all data for slider into dict type which slider need

[Styledict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nYEp.png)

this is my full code for showing map with "TimeSliderChoropleth" plugins:

```py
#Importing Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import folium
from folium import GeoJson
from folium.plugins import TimeSliderChoropleth
from branca.colormap import linear

#Creating Dataframe
df_house_sold = df[['year_mnth', 'zipcode']]
df_house_sold = df_house_sold.groupby(['year_mnth', 'zipcode'])[['zipcode']].agg(house_sold = 
                                                                                 ('zipcode', 'count')).reset_index()
df_house_sold = geo_df.merge(df_house_sold, on='zipcode').drop(columns='zipcode')
df_house_sold = df_house_sold.dissolve(by=['city', 'year_mnth'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
df_house_sold['datemodified'] = pd.to_datetime(df_house_sold['year_mnth'])

#Creating Time Index for slider
datetime_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_house_sold['datemodified'])
dt_index_epochs = datetime_index.astype(int) // 10**9
dt_index = dt_index_epochs.astype('U10')

#Converting df into dict type
styledata = {}
n_periods = len(dt_index)
n_sample = len(dt_index)
record_index = 0

for record in df_house_sold.index:
    df_house_sold['geometry'].at[record] = df_house_sold['geometry'][record]
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'color': df_house_sold.house_sold.to_numpy(),
        'opacity': 0*np.random.normal(size= n_periods)},
        index= dt_index)
    df = df.cumsum()
    df.sample(n_sample, replace=False).sort_index()
    df.loc[df.index == dt_index[record_index], 'opacity'] = np.ones(len(df.index[
        df.index == dt_index[record_index]]))
    
    styledata[record_index] = df
    record_index += 1
    
#Converting values into color
max_color, min_color = 0,0

for datemodified, data in styledata.items():
    max_color = max(max_color, data['color'].max())
    min_color = max(min_color, data['color'].min())
    
cmap = linear.BuPu_06.scale(min_color, max_color)

for city, data in styledata.items():
    data['color'] = data['color'].apply(cmap)
    data['opacity'] = (data['opacity'])
    data['opacity'] = (data['opacity'])
    
#Converting into Timeslider dict type requirements
styledict = {
    str(record): data.sort_index().reset_index().to_dict(orient='index') for 
    record, data in styledata.items()
}

df_house_sold['datemodified'] = df_house_sold['datemodified'].astype('str')

#Showing Map
b = folium.Map(location=[df['lat'].median() - 0.2, #0.1,
                         df['long'].median()+ 0.5], #0.8],
#                zoom_start= 9,
               zoom_start= 9,
#                tiles="Cartodb Positron",
               width="%80", height="%80")
slider = TimeSliderChoropleth(df_house_sold.to_json(), 
                              styledict = styledict, 
                              overlay = True).add_to(b)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = df_house_sold.to_json(),
    data = df_house_sold,
    columns = ['datemodified', 'house_sold'],
    key_on = 'feature.id',
    highlight = True,
    fill_color= 'BuPu',
    fill_opacity=0,
    line_opacity=0.0,
    legend_name = 'Number of Houses',
    ).add_to(b)

b
```

I used this as my reference: https://geohackweek.github.io/ghw2018_web_portal_inlandwater_co2/InteractiveTimeSeries.html

Comment: Please update the question with reproducible data and current code as text, not images.

Comment: @r-beginners thanks for ur response, I already did it and hope this will help

Comment: I was able to confirm the submission with the text of the code. The rest of the data is reproducible. Also, check the official [sample](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TimeSliderChoropleth.ipynb) case study.

Comment: @r-beginners I always get stuck on "styledict" part, when I'm trying to convert into pd.Dataframe.to_dict it always throws an error:

ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the reference `styledata` and `styledict`?

Comment: The contents of `styledict` is not match with `TimeDynamicGeoJson` wants.


It should have `index : { 'datetime': {the value of the datetime}`
Mine is:  `index : { index of every datetime in 1 area(map) :{'datetime', the value of the datetime, opacity}` @r-beginners

Comment: Your styledict is set up as an index where it is originally a timestamp of timeseries, so you set timeseries as the index in the creation of the data frame. My guess is that you need to make the timeseries a column.

Comment: I change my index from datetime to 0, 1, 2, etc (reset index and make datetime as a column). because if I'm not reset, the dict type `TimeDynamicGeoJson` not accept multiple/same datetime for every row which I have since 1 datetime can have multiple area data and that's why this error showed up `ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.`

Comment: The only way to make it unique is to increase the granularity of the original data. For example, you could add milliseconds. The only other way is to remove duplicates.

Comment: I think add milliseconds more visible to do, and I know I need to edit on `styledata` but can you help me how to add **1** for every loop on `dt_index (datetime)` since the datetime are index type and I don't know how to manipulate it.

Comment: I don't understand your data very well, so I don't quite understand why you would add +1 to the index in the loop process. If you want to avoid the same timestamp, you could create a new unique timestamp and update the index.